# What are the differences between std::shared_ptr and boost::shared_ptr in terms of overhead?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, boost, shared-ptr

The std shared pointers are the standard implementation after boost pointers, so what's the point for using the boost, are they more efficient, have lower overhead in memory\performance?

I'm working on a large codebase that consists of the non-homogeneous code parts that use one implementation of shared pointer or another. Doesn't matter the obvious type difference problems, what questioned me is how efficient are boost shared pointers are, and is there a point to use them other than supporting legacy code and compatibility of the project parts(some code compiled with older versions of C++).

I've seen several questions on the StackOverflow about this, but they're quite old and not answering my question about exact overhead.

I've wanted to try look into the compiler explorer, but haven't found one that supports boost, wonder if there is an online solution out there.

Comment: did you measure it? If you care about performance you need to measure.

Comment: what overhead to you mean? In memory footprint?

Comment: About boost in compiler explorer, godbolt.org does support boost actually, but like most libraries you need to add it via the libraries dialog. Here's some [proof that it works](https://godbolt.org/z/hETMca4TG) (code snippet comes from [here](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.smartpointers-shared-ownership))

Comment: Yes, I mean memory footprint, and in usage performance at all stages.

Comment: @harold, thanks, it's pretty helpful!

Comment: "_so what's the point for using the boost,_": That you might not be able to use C++11, mostly.

Comment: You can't generally compare `std::shared_ptr` to `boost::shared_ptr`. There is only one implementation of the latter, but many of the former. Which one are you comparing? I am not aware of any difference in the API/specification of the two that would inherently imply any performance difference.

Comment: Boost typically implements new C++ standard library features before they get adopted by the library implementations (libstdc++, libc++, Microsoft STL). Once they get there, there is usually no more reason to use Boost (at least in new projects).

Comment: I believe `boost::shared_ptr` works in C++03. Aside from that I doubt that it has any advantages over `std::shared_ptr`, especially in terms of performance. It might have some different features, I didn't check.

Comment: Performance is a weak basis to choose between `boost` and `std` versions of `shared_ptr`. Practically, measured performance difference is likely to be insignificant (and will vary between implementations). Historically, `shared_ptr` was introduced in boost 1.23.0, July 6, 2001 and influenced later introduction of `std::shared_ptr` (first ratified in C++11).  So I'd use `std::shared_ptr` unless I have specific requirements that Boost helps meet (e.g. supporting C++ compilers/libraries [predating C++11, post 2001], use of other Boost facilities with no counterpart (yet) in standard C++).

Comment: Since the Boost shared_ptr predates having atomics or threading as part of the language, and the Standard shared_ptr's control block (...which is an implementation detail, iirc) has some thread guarantees, I'd expect Boost shared_ptr to outperform standard shared_ptr if the performance testing leaned heavily on how the control block implementation ensures that thread safety (via mutexes or atomics).  In real code, that difference is *probably* negligible to minuscule.

Comment: @Eljay boost predating the point at which C++ stopped pretending that threads don't exist, doesn't mean it doesn't account for them. There are various different versions of `sp_counted_base` that use different thread-safe strategies. For example using Win32 atomic primitives such as `InterlockedIncrement`, using inline assembly to directly use `lock inc` and `lock xadd`, and a fallback to non-atomic operations protected by a pthread mutex. There is also a version for when threads are not used though.